# Unable to fetch Id of clicked record from table in Angular

Tags: angular, routerlink

I am working on Angular project. I want to fetch the Id of one record which I clicked, to pass in another component.

When I click the record **I am able to see the ID in Url**, but not able to fetch in new component.

This is my code of 1st component

```
<tr><td> <a routerLink="/devicelist/{{lst.ID.Value}}">{{lst.Failed}}</a> </td></tr>
```

Below code in 2nd Component to get ID, but at the time of appending `id` with url, it is showing **Undefined**.

Code of 2nd Comp

```
id = this.actRoute.snapshot.params['ID.Value']; 
ngOnInit() {  
    this.getFailedApps(this.id).subscribe((data:any) => {
    this.devices = data;
    console.log(data);
   })
}

public getFailedApps(Id) {
//here Id is Undefined
 return this._http.get(this.FailedDeviceUrl +Id+"/myapps", this.httpOptions); 
}
```

This is my Route file

```
 { path: 'devicelist/:id', component: DeviceListComponent }
```

Comment: How do you define 2nd `component` `route` in your `routing.ts` file? please include that too in your question

Comment: try logging `this.actRoute.snapshot.params` and see if you're accessing the correct property.

Comment: Move the assignment of `id` into the `ngOnInit` function. You'd probably be better off using the `ActivatedRoute.params` observable though.

Comment: @FahadHassan - please check my updated question

Answer (score 2):

Replace your routerLink with below code

```
<tr><td> <a [routerLink]="['/devicelist', lst.ID]" >{{lst.Failed}}</a> </td></tr>
```

Also declare parameter in the Route in AppModule.ts

```
{ path: 'devicelist/:id', component: YourComponent }
```

Then in the component read the param using the below code

```
  id: number;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
    });
  }
```